# SAM does not find python during deployment via GitHub Action

Tags: github-actions, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm setting up a Github action that will deploy my Python-based SAM application. However, the "sam deploy" command fails with an error that seems to indicate Python is not available to build the application, despite it having just been set up in the previous step:

[image: Github action flow]

```
Building codeuri: /github/workspace/\[...\]/source runtime: python3.7 metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: \['...'\]

Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:Resolver - Path resolution for runtime: python3.7 of binary: python was not successful
```

I can see that the python binary path is being passed as an env variable to the "SAM deployment" step: pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.12/x64

I also see that python is available via the "Check python version" step, where I do a simple "python -V", which returns the expected output.

Comment: Did you try using the same worklow as on the AWS doc? Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-github-actions-to-deploy-serverless-applications/

Comment: Thanks, switching out to that one instead of the custom-built one did the trick :)

Comment: Great, I'll add it as official answer 

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, following the official workflow on the [SAM AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-github-actions-to-deploy-serverless-applications/) resolved the issue.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      - uses: aws-actions/setup-sam@v1
      - uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ##region##
      # sam build 
      - run: sam build --use-container
```